# Python local variable 'charcheck' referenced before assignment, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to write a password validator application using python `tkinter`.
If the inserted password contains at least 2 numbers, at least 2 special characters and a length of at least 7, the password is considered Strong, else Weak.

If I enter a weak password the program will work, but if I enter a strong password I face this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/liana/projects/python/modification/modify.py", line 15, in submit
    charcheck += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'charcheck' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 

numcheck = 0
charcheck = 0

root=tk.Tk()  
root.geometry("600x400")  
passw_var=tk.StringVar() 

def submit(): 
    password=passw_var.get()    
    passw_var.set("")
    for i in range(len(password)):
        if(password[i]=='!' or password[i]=='@' or password[i]=='#' or password[i]=='$' or password[i]=='&' or password[i]=='%' or password[i]=='*'):
            charcheck += 1

        elif (ord(password[i])>=48 and ord(password[i])<=57):
            numcheck += 1 

    if (len(password)>=7 and charcheck>=2 and numcheck>=2):
        result_label = tk.Label(root, text='STRONG', font=('calibre',10, 'bold')).grid(row=3, column=2)

    else:
        result_label = tk.Label(root, text='WEAK', font=('calibre',10, 'bold')).grid(row=3, column=2)
       
passw_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Enter Your password: ', font = ('calibre',10,'bold')) 
   
passw_entry=tk.Entry(root, textvariable = passw_var, font = ('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*') 
   
sub_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Submit', 
                  command = submit) 
   
passw_label.grid(row=1,column=0) 
passw_entry.grid(row=1,column=1) 
sub_btn.grid(row=2,column=1) 
   
root.mainloop()
```

I'd like to know where I'm making a mistake.
Thank you

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: @quamrana What are the other methods than using `global` here? Maybe passing as parameters?

Comment: @quamrana yes use of global variable should not be used

Comment: Also as a tip, your `result_label` is `None`, meaning it cannot be edited elsewhere.

Comment: Just found that alternatively you can do as Rice said in the answer, and make your buttons command into `sub_btn=tk.Button(...,command = lambda:submit(numcheck,charcheck))`. This way you can get rid of `global` and resetting of values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variable referenced before assignment error python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727258/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-error-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move `charcheck` and `numcheck` into your function:

```py
def submit():
    charcheck = 0
    numcheck = 0
```

Comment: Ah, yes! It works now, thank you :)) I'll accept your answer in a few minutes

Comment: @Liana But keep in mind, that when ever the function is run, the value of `charcheck` and `numcheck` will be reset to 0, keep that in mind, might be helpful elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Use the `global` call to access the global variables

```
def submit(): 
    global numcheck, charcheck
    ......
```

Comment: I'm not convinced about the `global` thing. Those variables are not accessed outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `def submit` doesn't know about the `charcheck` variable. You have to say to your function that it's global:

```
def submit():
    global charcheck
    password=passw_var.get()    
    passw_var.set("")
    for i in range(len(password)):
```

So it works, adding `global charcheck`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
def submit(numbcheck,charcheck)



sub_btn=tk.Button(...,command = lambda:submit(numcheck,charcheck))
```

Comment: Would be better if you could also change this to show how the button should accept the function, as there are arguments parameters defined here.

Comment: @cool cloud ok but you have already told how to do that in the comment anyways i will edit it and put it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is looking for the variable name in it's local scope (within it's indentation). If you don't understand, look up Python Variable scope tutorials. You can resolve the problem in two ways; pass the variables as arguments or use the global keyword, such as in the code bellow:

```
def submit(): 
    global charcheck, numcheck, passw_var

    special_chars = "!@#$%^&*()_+[]\;',./{}|:\"<>?`~"
    password=passw_var.get()    
    passw_var.set("")
    for i in range(len(password)):
        if(password[i]) in special_chars:
            charcheck += 1

        elif (ord(password[i])>=48 and ord(password[i])<=57):
            numcheck += 1 

    if (len(password)>=7 and charcheck>=2 and numcheck>=2):
        result_label = tk.Label(root, text='STRONG', font=('calibre',10, 'bold')).grid(row=3, column=2)

    else:
        result_label = tk.Label(root, text='WEAK', font=('calibre',10, 'bold')).grid(row=3, column=2)
```

I've also edited the condition to check for special characters, this accounts for all and is more readable.